# How to get data to small and medium Widgets from different API swift?

Tags: swift, api, swiftui, widgetkit

```
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
    MonitorAPI.getInstallment(request: ["token": token] , completion: { result in
       }
    
    TotalAmountAPI.getTotal(completion: { result in
            competion(entry)
        }
}
```

I tried to send two API requests at one timeline. But unfortunately, my Medium Widget not showing information. How it is possible to handle it? I guess I should do generally another way.

Comment: The distinction to display different things depending on the `widgetFamily` is supposed to happen in the *Entry View* view

Comment: struct totalBalance_Widget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "totalBalance_Widget"
    
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            totalBalance_WidgetEntryView(entry: entry, mediumEntry: entry)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color.white)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName(“Total Widget")
        .description("Total Balance")
        .supportedFamilies([.systemSmall, .systemMedium])
    }
}
I also have like this